# Keep getting django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch when running more than 4 processes

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I have a script that processes data. When I call it with 1-3 processes it seems to work fine. However, once I get to trying to run it with 6 or more processes django errors out and I get *django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch*

I've read a few threads where they said they fixed it in a later version of psychopg2 so I tried upgrading my package and am currently on version 2.8, but I still get the error.

EDIT: One thing I've noticed is that the error happens when 2 process try to `bulk_create` at the same time. I am currently thinking about locking the database connection somehow, but I am not sure

The code that makes the processes

```py
 for profile_name in profiles_to_run:
            t1 = Process(target=self.run_profile_for_inspection, args = (odometer_start,odometer_end,inspection,profile_name,robot_inspection_id))
            t1.start()
            list_of_threads.append(t1)
            thread_count = thread_count + 1


        return list_of_threads

def run_profile_for_inspection(self, odometer_start, odometer_end,portal_inspection, profile_name, robot_inspection_id):
        self.out("Running inspection {} from {}m to {}m for {}".format(portal_inspection.pk, odometer_start, odometer_end,profile_name))
        rerun_profile = ReRunProfile(self._options['db_name'],self.out,profile_name, portal_inspection.pk, robot_inspection_id)
        # rerun_profile.set_odometer_start_and_end(odometer_start,odometer_end)
        rerun_profile.handle_already_created_inspections()
```

In ReRunProfile the get statement is what it errors out on if theres too many processes 
This is pseudo code

```py
   def handle_already_created_inspections(self):
        con = psycopg2.connect(dbname=self.database)
        time.sleep(10)
        robot_inspection_id = self.get_robot_inspection_id(self.portal_inspection_id)
        portal_inspection = Inspection.objects.get(pk=self.portal_inspection_id)
with con.cursor() as cur:
      cur.execute('Select * from data where start < odometer_start and end > odometer_end and profile = profile')
      count = 0
      processed_data = []
      for row in cur:
          processed_data.append(row.process())
          count = count + 1
          if count == 20:
             Profile.objects.bulk_create(processed_data) #errors out here too
             count = 0
             process_data = []
```

EDIT: Some one has asked what the bulk_create does.
Basically this program splits up data by distance and by profile and then process it and adds it to the database.

Comment: How many cores in your machine do you have?

Comment: I have 4 cores, but each of them can support 2 threads @eatmeimadanish

Comment: does this do this when you just use threads?

Comment: I tried this with threads before and it didn't do this, but that was a while ago, so I might not have tested it with many threads. However, threads are not useful for me as the point of my program is to speed up the processing of data, and with the python GIL the threads only work on one core vs multi process spreading the work over all the cores.

Comment: Without seeing what Bulk Create does it's impossible to really help you.  You may want to use the threaded connection pool out of psycopg2 to better handle the thread counts.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-db-pool/

Comment: I've added some pseudo code to show what the bulk_create does. Also thats a django method if no one knows

Comment: I still suggest using a connection pool to pull from, and sending the pool into your processes.